# How can Enterprise user move tested Self Service REST API to Production env?

Tags: amadeus

Currently I am an Enterprise user. I paid consultancy fee for implementation to Amadeus. Besides of those Enterprise API (Soap), I tested some of REST API in Self-Service and I also want to integrate into my application. In such case, do I need to pay separately as per pricing (https://developers.amadeus.com/pricing) stated in portal? Since I am already an Enterprise user and expected to be able to access REST API in Enterprise, can I request to waive such fee? Kindly advise.

Comment: How did you get access to the Enterprise API? Did you use the [official site](https://developers.amadeus.com/get-started/category?id=81&durl=336&parentId=NaN) and requested access?
How long did it take? (Haven't heard back from Amadeus.)

Answer (score 0):

Your account manager is the best person to help for this purpose.